# How can I have a variable command name to be interpreted and executed in shell configuration file?

Tags: shell, command-line, command, configuration-files

I have seen experts do something like:

>> -5

which jumps them up 5 levels of parent directories.

I'm like: **"This is so cool!"**

I am able to add this in my shell configuration file, but not in a very concise manner.

What I've done is add this to my .zshrc (works with .bashrc or other shells also) configuration file.

```
function -1 {
  cd ..
}
function -2 {
  cd ../..
}
function -3 {
  cd ../../..
}
```

This works.

Of course, what if I want to do -25? I probably wouldn't bother counting that much, but you never know. You can see how this would get lengthy. I want to avoid copy-paste type bad coding practices.

I've tried adding:

```
function "$0" {
#...
```

or

```
function "$@" {
#...
```

To try and grab the command input.
I am hoping I could then use regex to find the string, parse, make a loop for the value for any number of parent levels... I have code for this but am struggling with this first step:

The `"$@"` type commands don't work at all... even if it did, I'm not sure I want all commands to hit this block and not have the nice `zsh: <command provided>: command not found...` error message appear. Is there any way to avoid this?

This all boils down to having variable command names. Maybe this is the better question: is it even possible?

I'm sure someone has thought of this. I tried looking it up but haven't found anything yet.

Comment: What you're looking for is a "command not found" hook, so you can automatically replace the command with your own function. I'm not sure there's a way to do this.

Comment: [here](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Hook-Functions) is the list of `zsh` hook functions. There's no hook for a missing command. The closest is `preexec`, but it has no way to modify the command to create the `cd` command.

Comment: I think it can perform the `cd`, but you'll still get an error after that when it tries to execute the command.

Comment: If you want, you can take all or part of my functions [here](https://pastebin.com/7mh5vcBe), which are a bit more general: `up 4` cd's you up 4 levels. `up foo` cd's you up to the next directory containing _foo_ in its name, which I often find more convenient than counting the levels. If you want to have your `-4` syntax as well, you can in your .zshrc write a  loop (from 1 to 25) and create an alias for i.e. `-4` to `up 4`. I bet that in real life you will never want to go up more than, say, 8 levels.

Answer (score 1):

See below bash/zsh solution. Using the "evil eval" :-)
Works for bash (5.1.6), and zsh (5.8.1)

```
dd=..
for ((x=1 ; x<=25 ; x++)) { eval "function -$x { cd $dd ; }" ; dd+=/.. ; }
```

May also work on other sh-like program with minor modification.

Comment: Elegant. Magic! Doing `1` goes back down a directory (somehow based on history). I guess it uses the directory stack but I'm not sure how. Can you explain it? @dash-o

Comment: The "dd" variables starts with "..", and on every iteration is appended an extra layer with += "/.." - moving from '..' to '../..', '../../..', ... The "x" is just iteration number. Each iteration construct a function declaration - with -$x as the name, and the current $dd as the parameter from the "cd" command.
It does not directly uses the directory stack- this comes from the "cd" built-in. 
Hopes it make sense.

Comment: yep! It makes sense now, thanks :)  ... I see how it unravels the 'for' loop ... much like the functions I had originally. How does it make the positive numbers work though? @dash-o - that's the part that seems to be connected to the directory stack. If I login to a terminal and do 3 cd operations, then typing any number 1, 2 or 3 takes me to a directory I've been to... it is quite odd.

Comment: NM, my bad ... this must be some artifiact of my zsh implementation or something. It happens even when I don't have anything